# pushButton click fires twice

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I have some problem with pushButton. When I click on that button it seems that 
it clicked two times because function addDataToCsv write same data two times

```
class my_first_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(my_first_window, self).__init__()
        loadUi('untitled.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('My First Window')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.dialog = Second()
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        age = int(str(self.comboBox.currentText()))
        sex = str(self.comboBox_8.currentText())
        addDataToCsv(age, sex)
```

I cant find any solution for this.

Comment: Usually adding a time.sleep(0.1) or something like that makes sure you can't press a button twice in one click.

Comment: As I point out in the answer of the double question loadUi calls connectSlotsByName () connecting the signals and slots if the name of the slot has a certain format: on_sender_signal, in your case on_pushButton_clicked it fulfills it so Qt already connected it. You are then making another connection with self.pushButton.clicked.connect (self.on_pushButton_clicked), and in Qt if there are n connections between the same signal and slot that slot will be called n times if the signal is triggered (For more detail read my answer to the question duplicated).

Comment: [cont.]  So a possible solution is to change the name to the slot (on_pushButton_clicked to foo_method) or remove the connection you have made.

Comment: @vanderZonStef The GUI libraries have filters to handle those jumps so the sleep is not the solution.

Comment: @eyllanesc when You said remove the connection you have made you mean to call pushButton.clicked.disconnect()?

Comment: @Samvel no, I just said that you eliminate the line self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)

Comment: @eyllanesc Can I ask another question to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189587/discussion-between-samvel-and-eyllanesc).